# How should I place my scripts in my html files?

Tags: javascript, html

How should I place my scripts in my html files? Is there any difference to the browser?

1. To place all `<script>` elements before the `<body>`
2. To place all `<script>` elements to the top of the `<body>`
3. To place all `<script>` elements to the end of the `<body>`
4. To place all `<script>` elements after the `</body>`

Because I think I have used all 4 variants before, but I think there should be some consistency of the `</script>` elements placement.

Comment: How are 1 and 3 different? Please show some example markup of what you're talking about.

Comment: After the </body>? Never saw that before, I'm usually including the script(s) before the </body> tag, so that they are loaded after the rest of the document has been already loaded, not sure if that's the best practice, though.

Answer (score 8):

As a rule of thumb: Script tags should go at the bottom, unless they need to be higher up.

That's because they block the rest of the page from rendering until that script is done executing.

I think google recommends putting their analytics tracking script in the head. That's so if people leave your site before it's done loading, they can still track the visit.

Answer (score 0):

you can put almost everywhere, but the main ways to do it is by placing it in the `<head>` or after the body part. Place it after all body of the document will speed up the loading of your page

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on usage of the script files.
Higher in the document loads earlier but do you need them as soon as possible?

Google advises against loading javascript in the head (https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS).

But some tracking code (and google analytics also: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en) need to be placed in the head section of the document for proper collection of data.

Also javascript may be used for content loading etc. and therefore should be placed as high as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is considered to be a good practice to put all synchronously (the normal ones) loaded scripts to the bottom of `<body>`, since they block rendering of rest of the page.

However, asynchronously loaded scripts and trackers (i.e. [Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080)) can be placed wherever, since they are downloaded and executed parallelly and they should fire off as soon as possible.

As for the synchronous scripts, the order is determined by dependencies, ususally first go basic frameworks (i.e. jQuery), then its modules or plugins, then your own "inicialization" code.

Answer (score 0):

Usually is necessary to execute the script code after the page is completely loaded. In this case, the default option is right before the `</body>` tag.

There are some cases you need to include scripts before the page loads inside head tag.